# GOCD api to compare changes between two triggers in pipelines

Tags: pipeline, go-cd

I want to get all the changes between two builds in a pipeline in GOCD api.

I read the api documentation of GOCD. Couldn't find any api.

Like this url from gocd dashboard ->
https://localhost:8153/go/compare/pipeline_name/24/with/28

I need all the commits and authors as response as shown in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

GoCD doesn't have an API for compare runs for a pipeline. When even you inspect the API calls on the compare page, GoCD returns an HTML page that has all the revisions and their changes. But the actual diff is still rendered on page reload.

There's [already an issue](https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/3624) raised for this feature request. Please add your up-votes on the issue.